# Multiple storage drivers panic in private registry

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

I'm trying to deploy an S3-backed private docker registry and I'm getting an error when I try to start the registry container.  My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
registry:
  restart: always
  image: registry:2
  ports:
    - 5000:5000
  environment:
    REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ACCESSKEY: myKey
    REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_SECRETKEY: mySecret
    REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET: docker.registry.bucket
    REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ROOTDIRECTORY: registry/data
  volumes:
    - /home/docker/certs:/certs
```

And when I try to run `sudo docker-compose up -d` I get this error message:

```
registry_1 | panic: multiple storage drivers specified in configuration or environment: s3, filesystem
```

It seems like I'm missing something in my environment to explicitly choose s3 but it's not clear from the docs how to do this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was trying to override the storage configuration by using ENV vars. This workaround did the job (in json format):

```
{
    "REGISTRY_STORAGE": "s3",
    "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_REGION": <REGION>,
    "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET": <BUCKET_NAME>,
    "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ROOTDIRECTORY": <ROOT_PATH>,
    "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ACCESSKEY": <KEY>,
    "REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_SECRETKEY": <SECRET>
}
```

It looks like by defining `REGISTRY_STORAGE` we override the one in `config.yml`.

Answer (score 2):

There is `REGISTRY_STORAGE` environment variable missing. Need to be added to the "env" block.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because the `registry:2` image comes with a default config file `/etc/docker/registry/config.yml` which uses filesystem storage.

By adding S3 storage using environment variables there are multiple storage drivers, which I guess isn't supported.

I don't know of any way to remove configuration options with environment variables, so I think you'll probably need to create a config file and mount it as a volume (http://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#overriding-the-entire-configuration-file)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working using environment variables. Here's the snippet from my script:

```
     -e REGISTRY_STORAGE=s3 \
     -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ACCESSKEY=$AWS_KEY \
     -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_SECRETKEY=$AWS_SECRET \
     -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_BUCKET=$BUCKET \
     -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_REGION=$AWS_REGION \
     -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_S3_ROOTDIRECTORY=$BUCKET_PATH \
```

Comment: setting the REGISTRY_STORAGE=s3 ENV var got this working for me as well using the registry:2 image. No need to create a custom config.yaml and copy it into the container.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In My Case I had an environment variable for data in docker-compose.yml & S3 configuration in config.yml. It took some time but once the environment variables are commented out , registry:2 started properly.